# Re initializing objects

Tags: c#

I have an application which needs re initialization every time I process. something like :

```
private void method(int someValue, int someValue2)
{
 obj.val1 = someNewValue;
 obj1.Val2 = someNewValue2;
}
```

This method will be called repeatedly.  So I doubt is it okey to re initialize the object every time? something like;

```
private void method(int someValue, int someValue2)
{
 obj = new object();
 obj.Val1 = someNewValue;
 obj1.Val2 = someNewValue2;


}
```

I know assigning `null` to an object is nothing fruitful to do with.
or should I implement `IDisposable` ?  The problem is I need fresh values every time.Assigning will be ok in this scenario? I dont know what will happen to the already allocated object if i reinitialize as shown in second method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Reference objects" need to be disposed (by calling `Dispose()`) only if they use unmanaged memory. All such objects (in the .NET class libraries) implement `IDisposable`. Managed objects, on the other hand, are automatically collected (deleted) by the Garbage Collector behind-the-scene. In fact there is no direct way of deleting a managed object. You should not worry about such objects. As soon as they go out of scope, GC will eventually release their memory.

Simply assigning a new value to a managed variable releases the reference of the previous value and therefore makes it available for deletion by the GC.

Comment: Thats why I asked is it local... +1

Comment: last paragraph made me happy

Answer (score 3):

is this Object a custom class? If so i would write a "Reset()" method to do all the resetting you'd need.

for example you would call

```
private void method(int someValue, int someValue2)
{
 obj.Reset();
 obj.Val1 = someValue;
 obj1.Val2 = someValue2;
}
```

and in the Reset function you would do whatever you need to consider the object "re-initialised"

i.e

```
public void Reset()
{
    this.Val1 = 0;
    this.Val2 = 0;
    this.Name = "";
    this.Date = DateTime.MinDate;
    //You get the Idea, reset whatever needed to whatever you need.
}
```

using this function you can also then, in the constructor simply call "Reset();" so you know the values are the same when another method calls "Reset" on this object along with a new object being made.

Comment: This is the one I know useful and simple. Still lets see if we get any new suggestion.

Comment: Are both variables local? obj and obj1?

Comment: @Borna no global to this method

Comment: There is no global variable in C# tho, I was talking about variable scope, meaning where is it declated; is it method variable or class variable.